# HTML/JavaScript: Timer/Stopwatch doesn't reset (after stop)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
var c1 = 0;
var c2 = 0;
var c3 = 0;
var o1 = 0;
var o2 = 0;
var o3 = 0;
ID = window.setTimeout("start();", 100);

function start() {
    if (c1 == 59) {
        c1 = 00;;
        if (c2 == 59) {
            c2 = 00;
        }
        else c2++;
    }
    else c1++;

    if (c1 == 0 || c1 == 1 || c1 == 2 || c1 == 3 || c1 == 4 || c1 == 5 || c1 == 6 || c1 == 7 || c1 == 8 || c1 == 9) o1 = "0" + c1;
    else o1 = c1;
    if (c2 == 0 || c2 == 1 || c2 == 2 || c2 == 3 || c2 == 4 || c2 == 5 || c2 == 6 || c2 == 7 || c2 == 8 || c2 == 9) o2 = "0" + c2;
    else o2 = c2;
    if (c3 == 0 || c3 == 1 || c3 == 2 || c3 == 3 || c3 == 4 || c3 == 5 || c3 == 6 || c3 == 7 || c3 == 8 || c3 == 9) o3 = "0" + c3;
    else o3 = c3;

    document.forms[0].elements[0].value = o3 + ":" + o2 + ":" + o1;
    ID = window.setTimeout("start();", 100);
}​
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frm1">
            <input type="text" name="timer1">
            <input type="button" name="but1" value="start" onClick="c1=0; c2=0; c3=0; o1=0; o2=0; 

o3=0; start();">
            <input type=button name="but2" value="stop" onClick="window.clearTimeout(ID);">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>​
```

[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4a54/).

Status Bar gives the error: Object doesn't support this action.

Comment: What the heck is this: `    if (c1 == 0 || c1 == 1 || c1 == 2 || c1 == 3 || c1 == 4 || c1 == 5 || c1 == 6 || c1 == 7 || c1 == 8 || c1 == 9) o1 ` ?!

Comment: @gdoron same as `(c1 >= 0 && c1 <= 9)` :p

Comment: @sg3s. Yes I wrote that in the answer... Yuck!

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: @gdoron , @ThiefMaster; http://jsfiddle.net/7SZKP/   this works fine even after string in function-name...?

Comment: Using a string in `setTimeout` works just fine, it's just considered outdated as you can use the function name directly nowadays. The difference between that code and the one that isn't working is the function name. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error in Internet Explorer because there is already a variable `start` in use, either by the browser itself, or by jsFiddle. After you have used it to define the function, it's for some reason changed into a variable containing the string `"fileopen"`.

If you rename the function `start` to something else, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/yqsmy/

Anyhow, you should rather use an interval instead of a timeout for this:

Javascript:

```
var c1, c2, c3, ID = null;
startTimer();

function startTimer() {
    if (ID != null) {
        stopTimer();
    }
    c1 = 0;
    c2 = 0;
    c3 = 0;
    ID = window.setInterval(run, 100);
}

function stopTimer() {
    window.clearInterval(ID);
    ID = null;
}

function run() {
    c1++;
    if (c1 == 60) {
        c1 = 0;
        c2++;
        if (c2 == 60) {
            c2 = 0;
        }
    }

    var o1 = (c1 <= 9 ? "0" : "")  + c1;
    var o2 = (c2 <= 9 ? "0" : "")  + c2;
    var o3 = (c3 <= 9 ? "0" : "")  + c3;
    document.forms[0].elements[0].value = o3 + ":" + o2 + ":" + o1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="frm1">
  <input type="text" name="timer1">
  <input type="button" name="but1" value="start" onclick="startTimer();">
  <input type="button" name="but2" value="stop" onclick="stopTimer();">
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/B4a54/7/

If you want the timer to be *exact*, you should save the start time in a variable, then subtract that from the current time to get the elapsed time, and only use the interval to display the elapsed time.

Comment: Should not have started with 'start')

Answer (score 1):

[**Fixed fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4a54/6)

You should pass the function reference.

changed from:

```
ID = window.setTimeout("start();", 100);
```

to

```
ID = window.setTimeout(start, 100);
```

---

Note that it's a very "unattractive" code...

`if (c1 == 0 || c1 == 1 || c1 == 2 || c1 == 3 || c1 == 4 || c1 == 5 || c1 == 6 || c1 == 7 || c1 == 8 || c1 == 9)`

You can simply check the boundaries:

```
if (c1 >= 0 && c1 <= 9)
    o1="0"+c1;
```

Comment: Since `c1` can never be negative `if( c1 <= 9 )` is enough.

Comment: @Juhana. True, but with that code, I'm not touching a thing... :)

Comment: Guys, are you sure that you clicked on the 'start' button after 'stop' in the 'fixed'-fiddles? Where's the reset?  
And, saving it in a single file on desktop, IE9 throws error/warning, "Object doesn't support this action"?

Comment: @popstack. it reset the time when you click "start" again. Hey it's your code, not mine...

Comment: -1 Although true, this doesn't even try to address the main problem that the OP has.

Comment: @Guffa. which is? what is missing?

Comment: @gdoron: "Status Bar gives the error: Object doesn't support this action."

Comment: @Guffa. Well.. with the fixed code it doesn't happen. If you really want I can upvote your answer...

Comment: @gdoron: With the "fixed" code it still happens. I have tried it, and the OP has tried it.

Comment: @Guffa. I'm sorry mate, but I don't see any errors in my console, what are you talking about? are you sure you're didn't try old fiddle?

Comment: @gdoron: What browser are you testing this in? The error only occurs in IE, as the OP said.

Comment: @Guffa `chrome`, I can't see `IE` in the guy question\comments, can you please help me out?

Comment: @Guffa. so you downvoted because only in a comment he said he have problems with `IE` **HA?!** Good luck with that attitude. I'm done here.

Comment: @gdoron: No, I downvoted because the answer doesn't even try to address the main problem of the question, just like I said.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<input type="button" name="but1" value="start" onClick="c1=0; c2=0; c3=0; o1=0; o2=0; o3=0; start();">
```

to this

```
<input type="button" name="but1" value="start" onClick="c1=0; c2=0; c3=0; o1=0; o2=0; o3=0; window.clearTimeout(ID); ID=window.setTimeout('start();',100); start();">
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem, it adds a problem. In a browser where it works, it will make the second and third count right after each other, so it will appear to count 1,3,4 instead of 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Stopping the timeout if it's currently running makes sense, but you are still starting it twice.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an improved timer example](http://jsbin.com/akupuc/5/edit#source)

It've been done using jquery, but it's not a problem write same without any library. Also solved double start click problem :)

Also you can change setInterval - call it only when timer is working and clear it, when it stopped. All of that is up to you.